# Sort rows of data frame by shifting the rows so that the maximum value is on the top

Tags: r

I have a data frame like below, values of which needs to be sorted.

```
Name Bin Value
a    1   10
a    2   1000
a    3   1
a    4   100
b    1   20
b    2   2
b    3   200
b    4   2000
```

I wish that the maximum value goes to the top with keeping the relative position of values to the other values, so that the new order looks like below.

```
Name Bin Value
a    1   1000
a    2   1
a    3   100
a    4   10
b    1   2000
b    2   20
b    3   2
b    4   200
```

It is not just bring the maximum `Value` to the top, but the whole sequence of `Value` needs to be shifted with maximum `Value` like `a` `1` is always below `a` `1000` in both old and new `data.frame`.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but just bring the maximum `Value` to the top did not solve my problem. The `Name` `a` have `Value` of `1000` followed by `1`, which followed by `100`, and so on. So it is not just max `Value` if you look at my new data frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a function which takes a vector and shifts it upwards moving the maximum to the top and then shifting the values before the maximum to the bottom.  Use `ave` to apply that to Value by Name.

```
max2top <- function(x) {
  wx <- which.max(x) - 1
  if (wx == 0) x else c(tail(x, -wx), head(x, wx))
}
transform(DF, Value = ave(Value, Name, FUN = max2top))
```

giving

```
Name Bin Value
1    a   1  1000
2    a   2     1
3    a   3   100
4    a   4    10
5    b   1  2000
6    b   2    20
7    b   3     2
8    b   4   200
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "Name Bin Value
a    1   10
a    2   1000
a    3   1
a    4   100
b    1   20
b    2   2
b    3   200
b    4   2000"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

Comment: Have updated to circularly rotate vector upwards so that maximum is at top.